# End of script output before headers

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, ubuntu, cgi

When I create the file test.py (see code below) in an editor on Windows (I tried Netbeans, PyCharm and Notepad++) and upload it to the server (Ubuntu) I receive this error:

**End of script output before headers: test.py**

But when I create the file directly on the server using vi command line editor the page is displayed without any error. Any idea how to fix this issue ?

Here's the code for test.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# send content type
print("Content-Type: text/html\n\n")

print("Good")
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that's because of windows carriage return characters.

These are two characters:

```
\r is carriage return;
\n is line feed.
```

Two characters combined represent a new line on Windows. Whereas on Linux, \n represents new line.

*Notepad++* has an option to specify which format you want to use:

Go to *Settings -- > Preferences*  and the choose linux:

[image]